# Why is my conditional formatting not working?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I have a column of consecutive dates.  I would like to highlight the rows for Saturdays. I have Conditional Formatting applied to `$2:$112`, and the formula for formatting is `=weekday($a2) = 7`. However, this is not working. Suggestions?
[I checked that (a) the weekday function properly reads the date values, and (b) the unformatted dates are the Excel date-values].

Here is a screenshot of my sheet and the Conditional Formatting menu. To be clear: I want the highlighting to be the whole row where the date in column A represents a Saturday.

[image: Screenshot of Excel Sheet I am trying to format]

Answer (score 0):

You are using an Excel absolute cell reference (with $ sign),
which uses only the cell `A2` for all weekdays.
You should be using a relative cell reference to make it work
differently for different dates:

```
=weekday(a2) = 7
```

Reference:
[Why use dollar sign ($) in Excel formulas - absolute and relative cell references](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/11/25/relative-absolute-reference-excel/).

Comment: I tried using just the relative reference (a2), but that didn't work. In any case, I'm using an absolute reference only on the COLUMN, but not the row. I always want the weekday() function to reference column A, but to change rows. So, the reference $A2 should do that: Absolute reference for column, relative reference for row.

Comment: I think I need to see an example spreadsheet of yours. Could you post it online (OneDrive, Dropbox etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to specify the range for the formula to apply, via Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules:
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Right now the Applies to box reads $2:$112 to refer to the whole row.

Answer (score 0):

If the Range `$2:$112` full of date values? If not, just select the range with date values and it will work with `=weekday(A2)=7`:
[image]